# Diffeomorphism on a 2 form

Tags: differential-geometry

If $\Sigma$ is a 2-dimensional worldsheet, and $X^{\mu}(\Sigma)$ is the embedding in target space how does a 2-form $B_{\mu\nu}$ transform, under diffeomorphism on world sheet, generated by vector field $\xi^k$ (with $k=0,1$)?

Comment: [pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(differential_geometry)#Pullback_of_multilinear_forms)